# 3-Way Light Switch Replacement Question

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I have a 3-way light switch that I am trying to replace upstairs. The light switch controls a hall light, and there are 2 other light switches that control the same light. I've already replaced the other 2 light switches with new ones & copying the setup. However, the 3rd switch is different than the other two.

**Current Switch Setup**

- Two bundles of wires coming from the top of the box - each with a white, black, and red wire
- The red wires are capped off together (different from the other two switches where the red wire was used)
- One set of Black & White wires are connected to two terminals on the top of the current switch
- Remaining Black & White wires are connected to two terminals on the bottom of the current switch

Since a 3-way switch has a different setup than the current switch, I'm wondering how I should wire the new switch? Cap off the white wires with a third wire that connects to the new Switch & connecting both black wires to the common & line terminals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is a 4-way switch. 2 travelers from each direction but no hot or switched hot. You have a 3-way on each b end.You can have any number of 4-ways in between.

The reds are carrying switched hot from one end to the fixture at the other end.